# How can I change a file mod to chmod+x in linux?

Tags: python, linux, shell

I have a `helloworld.sh` file in my Linux. When I try to simply run it through a python script with `subprocess.call('./hello.sh')`, it shows the output of `permission denied`.

I have tried this method found online but it is not working `os.chmod("hello.sh", 0o664)`. I want to change the permission of the file through a python script to `chmod+x`.

Please guide me through the syntax. I also have searched online but it is not working. I have a Debian-based Linux.

Comment: `os.chmod("hello.sh", 0o755)` to give execution rights. Are you generating the script?

Comment: no, I have a script in the .sh file I am executing it through python script but on execution it gives rise to Permission denied error.

Comment: 6 is r+w, not r+w+x; and 4 is only r. Why do you think 644 _should_ be equivalent to a result of applying `+x`?

Answer (score 2):

This should add executable permissions to `user`, `group` and `other` in a platform independent way while maintaining any original permissions. I don't own a Windows machine to test on, but the documentation of `Path.chmod()` says that it should be supported on Windows as well, although all bits except the read-only bit will be ignored.

```
from pathlib import Path
import stat

path = Path("/path/to/file")
original_st_mode = path.st_mode
path.chmod(original_st_mode | stat.S_IXUSR | stat.S_IXGRP | stat.S_IXOTH)
```